# qt.qpa.plugin Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "..." even though it was found

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt5

I know this issue has been addressed many time in different forums but I feel like I tried every solution and I couldn't make it work. I'm working on an opencv and pyqt project, I'm using this packages:

```
opencv-python==4.5.5.64
opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.64
PyQt5==5.15.0
PyQt5-sip==12.8.1
```

I've installed them in that order using pip. I already tried using Venv form Pycharm, Virtualenv manually installed, and Conda. I've also tried to use a colleague's venv which was working on her Ubuntu machine(20.04). The problem originally presented on Ubuntu 22.04, but I've tried a VM with Ubuntu 20.04 freshly installed and it failed again.

I've reinstalled libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxcb-util.so.1 and libxcb-xinerama0. this is the debug log(QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1):

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/c_rehash"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/c_rehash' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/c_rehash' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/captoinfo"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/clear"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/clear'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/infocmp"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/infocmp'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/infotocap"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzcat"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzcmp"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzdiff"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzegrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzfgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzless"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzma"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmadec"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmadec'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmainfo"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmainfo'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmore"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/ncursesw6-config"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/ncursesw6-config' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/ncursesw6-config' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/openssl"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/openssl'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip3' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip3' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pylupdate5"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pylupdate5' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pylupdate5' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyrcc5"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyrcc5' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyrcc5' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3-config"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyuic5"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyuic5' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyuic5' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/reset"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tset'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3_analyzer"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3_analyzer' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3_analyzer' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tabs"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tabs'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh8.6"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/toe"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/toe'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tput"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tput'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tset"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tset'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/unlzma"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/unxz"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wheel"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wheel' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wheel' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish8.6"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ld"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ld'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda_cos7-linux-gnu-ld"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ld'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzcat"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzcmp"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdec"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdec'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzegrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzfgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}
```

Comment: what did you do to cause _that_ kinda output? [mre] or thorough description of the steps please

Comment: i tried to run a PyQt5 app im developing. I'm working on a team and it works perfectly for them but not for me. The main.py file includes qtwidgets, a qt view and fails when doing " app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) "

Comment: if anyone encounters this problem i ended up fixing it by building open cv from source instead of using pip

Comment: oh, you installed BOTH opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python. that commonly causes issues. install exactly one of those. any of them contains the base modules... though I have no idea why that would affect Qt at all.